# php Fatal error: Method name must be a string

Tags: php

why i get this error? how fix it? when run on server get Fatal error: Method name must be a string line 8

```
class Model extends Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    protected function Load()
    {
        $a = file_properties();  
        $x0 = $this->$a["x0"]();       line 8 error
        $x0 = $this->$a["x1"]($x0);
        $this->$a["x2"]($x0);
    }
}
```

please help me.

Comment: So what `$x0 = $this->$a["x0"]();` is supposed to be?

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($this->$a["x0"])` ??

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yeah you are right

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
protected function Load()
{
    $a = file_properties(); 

    $f = $a['x0'];
    $x0 = $this->$f();

    $f = $a['x1'];
    $x0 = $this->$f($x0);

    $f = $a['x2'];
    $this->$f($x0);
}
```

Obviously the values `$a['x0']`, `$a['x1']`, `$a['x2']` must be strings and hold a valid method name for the class.

Comment: isn't fixed error in $x0 = $this->$f(); my php version is 5.2.17

Comment: Please read my answer better: **Obviously the values `$a['x0']`, `$a['x1']`, `$a['x2']` must be strings and hold a valid method name for the class.** what are they're actual values?

Answer (score 1):

Right, there's a variety of possible reasons for your code throwing up errors:

- What is `$a["x0"]`? is it a string? If so, does the method even exist?
- Ambiguity: The preprocessor might have a hard time working out what you're trying to do, should the string value of `$a` be used to reference a property, that might be an array, that has a key `"x0"`, which in turn might be a Closure instance, or a string that is a method name? use cruly braces to be clear: `$this->{$a["x0"]}();`
- At no point are you cheking if the method exists, let alone if it can be called... where are your `method_exists($this, $a["x0"])` and `is_callable(array($this, $a["x0"]))` checks?
- Your code is flawed from the off, it's so incredibly error-prone... I wouldn't even bother working this one out. I'd set about rethinking my approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve here, and start over.